# Unable to erase and format new USB drive

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, usb

I have a new out-of-the-box 16GB USB flash drive and I am unable to erase it in macOS. I've tried via Terminal command, Disk Utility nothing works.

[image: one]

This is what I get when I insert my USB drive

[image: two]

This is how it looks in my Disk Utility

[image: three]

I am out of options after 2 days of researching and getting no luck! Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please add the relevant lines from Terminal command `diskutil list`.

Comment: @Gilby you mean command i used? `diskutil erasedisk ExFat myUsb disk2`

Comment: Some older USB keys have a physical write-lock switch. Perhaps this has one? Also, some USB keys just fail to format at all because they got zapped somehow. Chuck this one in the trash and move on. :-)

Comment: @IconDaemon I open the box of this usb last night (brand new) it works just fine on PC but on Mac....

Comment: I meant `diskutil list` so we can see the partitions which are on the disk and their format along with the partition table type.

Comment: Maybe some troubleshooting tips at [this page](https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/fix-corrupted-usb-flash-drive-on-mac.html) may help you find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

First list the disks:

```
diskutil list
```

Then try:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ UntitledUFS /dev/disk*
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I couldn't use Disk Utility like I've been used to. Instead I ran "diskutil list" I ID'd the USB drive as disk4 and then ran this and it worked:

```
diskutil eraseDisk exFAT MYUSB /dev/disk4
```

I'm now happily copying a 33GB wedding video onto the Sandisk 64 GB flash drive.